# Programatically evaluate client-side JavaScript that edits DOM without a browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, dom, bots

I am wondering if it is possible to do something like this:

1. Request site I am scraping.
2. The site has client-side and possibly server-side javascript that makes requests and edits the DOM.

Ex.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {        
(function(){
  $(function(){
    $(atob('BASE64 HERE'))
        .append(
            $(atob('BASE64 HERE'))
            .val('VALUE TO ADD INTO ELEMENT')
         );
    });
  })(jQuery);
});
```

3. Would it be possible to run this code without ever loading a headless/headed browser of any kind?

I am running in NodeJS.

Comment: Maybe [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) if you do not deeply care about those scripts and what they do, i.e. loading scripts that load other scripts and then mutate DOM

Comment: @Aivaras this is exactly what I need. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a comment on my post @Aivaras helped point me to [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) which does exactly what I need.

By running scripts 'dangerously' I can run any dom-editing scripts on the page without opening any headless browsers such as Puppeteer.